# How can one project a matrix so that its components are within the range of [0,1]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across a text that mentions obtaining a matrix $S$ from a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ in the following manner:

> $S = Proj_{[0,1]}(B)$,

> where $Proj_{[0,1]}(.)$ is a function that projects a real matrix into the range of $[0,1]$.

The matrix B here is to be transformed so that each element of the matrix S is in the range of [0,1].

I have been finding it difficult to figure out, what is such a possible projection function?

Source: https://doi.org/10.1109/TNNLS.2021.3093426 (eqn. 12)

Comment: The provided link is not free-to-read, so I can't access the source for more details. Does it mean transforming a matrix so each element is in the range of $[0, 1]$, or mapping a matrix to a single real number in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: The matrix is transformed so that each element of the matrix is in the range [0,1].

Comment: I'm wondering whether it could be a simple $S = \frac{B - \min\{B\}}{\max\{B\}-\min\{B\}}$, however I'm not confident whether this operation can be called a projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified in equation 11 just before

\begin{equation}
S^* = \text{argmin}_{S,0\leq S\leq 1} \left\| S-B \right\|_F
\end{equation}

So
\begin{equation}
S^*_{i,j}
=
\begin{cases}
B_{i,j},& 0\leq B_{i,j} \leq 1\\
0, & B_{i,j} <0\\
1, & B_{i,j} >1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.